# Condition on function so that it is bounded on closed intervals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I have a function $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb R$. I need the function to be bounded on all closed subintervals of $(a,b)$ (of course the bound may be different for each subinterval).

This is the case for example if $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, or if it is monotonic.

Are there other conditions on $f$ that ensure that it is bounded on closed intervals? Ideally, what is the “most general” such condition?

Comment: Hm. Maybe [_bounded variation function_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) is the answer

Comment: If a function is continuous on a compact space, then it is bounded there.

Comment: @Allawonder But, in my case, $(a,b)$ is not compact

Comment: Yes but closed subintervals of $(a,b)$ are compact.

Comment: @paf Sorry, I don't follow. What would the condition on $f$ be, then?

Comment: Simply the continuity, as @Allawonder told you. (if $a$ and $b$ are finite)

Comment: @paf Ah, ok. But, as I state in my question, I'm looking for more general conditions than continuity

Comment: I don't know if there's a general condition other than the trivial one: $f$ bounded on all $K \subset (a,b)$, with $K$ compact.
I mean continuity, monotony, and bounded variation are all sufficient conditions, but they aren't necessary. Example: Dirichlet function is not continuous, nor monotonic, nor BV but it is bounded (everywhere).

Comment: @francescop21 Good point

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, sorry for the typo. Maybe you could go with $f \in L_{loc}^\infty \left((a,b)\right)$ if you're willing to give up some null sets where $f$ may be not bounded. It isn't a great improvement though.

Comment: @francescop21 . The condition is very general and does not require $f$ to be  Lebesgue-measurable. The condition i equivalent to saying that $f$ is locally bounded on $(a,b)$ but that is about all there is to it.

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not sure what you mean by more general. I mean, continuity is the least amount of niceness you can ask from an arbitrary function. In your OP, you begin, 'I have a function...' Perhaps if you told us more about the function we might understand you better and be able to help.

Comment: @francescop21 Is monotony indeed sufficient? One can construct unbounded monotone functions on compact intervals.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you're right! I forgot the requirement on $f$ to be $\mathscr{L}$-measurable

Comment: @Allawonder Can you? Consider $f$ monotone non-decreasing on $[a,b]$, then $f(a) \le f(x)\le f(b)\quad\forall x\in [a,b]$, hence $f$ is bounded (if $f$ is non-increasing the inequalities are reversed).

Comment: @francescop21 But OP requires the domain to be open, and that $f$ should be bounded on an *arbitrary* subinterval of this domain. This is what makes it hard to think anything other than plain old continuity would do.

Comment: @LuisMendo The second part of your second paragraph in the OP is false. Monotonicity is insufficient. Consider, for example, $f:(0,1)\to\mathbf R$ defined as follows. Whenever $0<x<1/2$, let $f(x)=0$ and let $f(x)=n\,\,\forall\,\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\le x<\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^{n+1}}$ whenever $n$ is an integer $>0.$

Comment: @Allawonder No, both OP and your previous comment require $f$ to be bounded on any **closed** (*i.e.* compact) subinterval of $(a,b)$. So monotony does the trick, as well as continuity. But these conditions are not necessary, you can go without them (see Dirichlet function).

Comment: @francescop21 O yes, it does. I'm muddled up right now. It seems then that piecewise continuity is what OP needs. I'm going to bed now. Continue this tomorrow.

Comment: @Allawonder Thanks. The function is actually arbitrary. It's a complicated probability-theory setting, probably irrelevant here, but the function is unknown. I'd like to require the minimum I can of it. Anyway, I think I have been able to prove that my arbitrary function is always continuous (because of how it arises), so that would solve my issue

Comment: I just found what I wanted, or something very close: "locally bounded function". I've posted an answer. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

The concept of [local boundedness](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1337086093) comes very close to what I wanted.

A function is locally bounded if for every point in its domain there is a neighbourhood where the function is bounded. This implies (linked reference, theorem 5) that the function is bounded on closed intervals. Also, conrtinuity implies local boundedness.